# What is the alternative to Messenger Broadcast API (Deprecated) for Broadcast Messages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger, facebook-send-api

I was previously using the [Messenger Broadcast API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/broadcast-api/) to send regular updates to ALL users on my Facebook chat bot. These updates include daily news, feature updates etc. However now that the API is deprecated, I can't find any alternative API to do the same thing.

One possible alternative to this is to iterate through all the user's of my app and manually send them messages using the [SEND API.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/) However this is quite inefficient and you can easily hit maximum [rate limits](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages#limits) as mentioned in the documentation. So I would have to send out this manual update over a long period of time slowly to avoid hitting the rate limits. This feels like a hacky fix when the Broadcast API provided such a simple solution.

I can't seem to find any obvious alternative to the Broadcast API in Facebook's documentation. Is there any alternative API/technique I can use for my use-case?

Comment: The broadcast API link that you included say: "We recommend apps to migrate to the new policy and migrate to use the Send API as soon as possible."

Comment: The problem is the Send API dosen't handle this use case very well. If I have a large number of users, I would quickly hit rate limits. I would have to slowly send the messages over a period of time throughout the day. 

It seems strange they would recommend such a complicated fix when they already had a very elegant solution to this exact problem. 

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe they wanted to stop the spamming